# Is the convolution operator continuous in the weak topology?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the convolution operator $L^p\ast L^q\rightarrow L^r$, where $\frac{1}{r}+1=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$, of course if we equip $L^p, L^q, L^r$ with the norm topology, then $\ast$ is continuous by Young's inequality.

However if we equip $L^p$ and $L^q$ with the weak topology, but equip $L^r$ with the norm or weak topology, then is $\ast$ still continuous?

Comment: I think the only thing that works is that you can take $L^r$ and one of the two others with the weak topology, but the last in strong topology.

Comment: This should be like compactness when $p,q \neq \infty$. Also when $r= \infty$ and $1< p,p’ =q<\infty$ you get a counter-example with $\chi_{[j,j+1]}$